# Passing a PHP variable to JavaScript For AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So my workflow is that onClick of an list element, my JS initiates a PHP AJAX request to build a card object.  The $content is a card (similar to KickStarter) of topic data.  What I'm trying to do is a pass the 'topic_id' of each topic-instance so that I can then use it in the success function, to then initiate ANOTHER AJAX request (but to Discourse).

With attempt 2), I get a null when viewing its value in the web inspector.

The AJAX requests (the console.log() of the variable I want to get returns a blank line in the web console):

```
$.post( "/wp-content/mu-plugins/topic-search.php", { topicID: $topicFilter, filterBy: $sortByFilter },
        function( data ) {
            console.log(topic_id);
            data = data.trim();
            if ( data !== "" ) {
                //get the participants data for avatars
                $.getJSON('http://ask.example.com/t/' + topic_id + '.json', function() {
```

---

The end of topic-search.php, which echoes out the built up card. Script is supposed to return the topic_id variable for use in the success function.

```
    }


    //One attempt:     echo $content; //
    //Another attempt: echo json_encode(array('data' => $content, 'topic_id' => $row['topicid']));//
}

?>

<script>

var topic_id = "<?php echo $row['topicid'] ?>";

</script>
```

---

Comment: Why not directly php code instead of js. Btw you did not print js var. May be use document.write

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In php

```php
$inputJson = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJson, true); //Convert JSON into array
```

In javascript

```js
    var $url = '/wp-content/mu-plugins/topic-search.php';
    var $json = JSON.stringify({topicID: $topicFilter, filterBy: $sortByFilter});

    $.ajax({
        url: $url,
        type: "POST",
        data: $json,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){//you will have the body of the response in data
          //do something
        },
        error: function(data){
          //do something else
        }
    });
```

EDIT:

This will request `$url` with the `$json` data. You will have it available on `$input` on the server side as an array. You can then on the server prepare a response with a json body that you will have available on the success function as the `data` variable.